# The strange wall or background in the cavern layer of Terrarria

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I was in the underground cavern and found this.     What is it?[image]

Comment: Note the background.

Comment: I think it's like a mini Biome/structure as you can see the purple stuff around the stone above you, similar to those mine-shafts you can find though i don't know what it is exactly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're referring to this tile:

[image]

This is the [Obsidian Back Wall](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Obsidian_Back_Wall). Other wall patterns can found found [at this helpful wiki article](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wall).